# Page header with box sections & page border

Tags: tikz-pgf, fancyhdr, pgfplotstable, geometry

So I'm currently working on converting some documents used in our university to use LaTeX, and I'm stuck on a bit of a hangup. I've been able to nail down all the basics, using plotting, etc; but I can't seem to figure out how I can re-create the headers and page look.

Here's an example of the header on the title page (the upper section will be present throughout the doc):

[image]

I've been able to create the page border with pgfpages, but I cant seem to make the coherent page table show up and work. Is this stuff even possible with LaTeX?

Comment: Yes everything is possible with LaTeX.  To do those page headers (ie the grayish boxes with descriptions, lib num, rev, page) you want to define a page style.  To do the title page box (ie the darker box with the tell-tale MSWord table marker at the top) you probably want to redefine what `\maketitle` does.  All of this should go into a new document style.

Comment: Thanks @Thruston, I will definitely be looking up other packages and methods to try and make the title information more dynamic as I use more LaTeX features. Are there any guides in particular that you think would point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here's one possibility using the [`background`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/background) and [`tikzpagenodes`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikzpagenodes) packages to produce both the header and the frame; the code contains some explanatory comments:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[scale=1,angle=0,opacity=1,color=black!60]{background}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter

% A length to control the separation of the text and the frame
\newlength\AUCFrameSep
\setlength\AUCFrameSep{2cm}

% A length to control the height of the minipages used in the header
\newlength\AUCBoxHt
\setlength\AUCBoxHt{1.5cm}

% A length to control the width of the frame
\newlength\AUCFrameWd
\setlength\AUCFrameWd{\textwidth}
\addtolength\AUCFrameWd{2\AUCFrameSep}

% Definition of the user commands to fill the header
% Initially they are empty
\newcommand\Description[1]{\gdef\@ACUdescription{\textsc{#1}}}
\newcommand\LibNum[1]{\gdef\@ACUlibnum{\textsc{#1}}}
\newcommand\Rev[1]{\gdef\@ACUrev{#1}}
\Description{}
\LibNum{}
\Rev{}

% Command to build each one of the boxes for the header
% \AUCBox{<width>}{<title>}{<contents>}
% The optional argument controls the height of the minipages;
% default value= \AUCBoxHt 
\newcommand\AUCBox[4][\AUCBoxHt]{%
\fbox{\begin{minipage}[t][#1][t]{#2}
\begin{flushleft}\footnotesize #3\end{flushleft}
\centering#4
\end{minipage}}}

% We define the background: the header and the frame
\backgroundsetup{%
contents={%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\draw 
  ([xshift=-\AUCFrameSep,yshift=-2cm]current page text area.north west|-current page.north west)
  rectangle
  ([xshift=\AUCFrameSep,yshift=-1.5\AUCFrameSep]current page text area.south east);
\node[anchor=north west,xshift=-\the\dimexpr\AUCFrameSep+\fboxrule\relax,yshift=-2cm,inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt] at (current page text area.north west|-current page.north west)
{%
  \sffamily\small%
  \setlength\fboxsep{2pt}%
  \AUCBox{\dimexpr.6\AUCFrameWd-3\fboxrule-8\fboxsep\relax}{Description}{\@ACUdescription}\kern-\fboxrule%
  \AUCBox{.175\AUCFrameWd}{Lib Num}{\@ACUlibnum}\kern-\fboxrule%
  \AUCBox{0.10\AUCFrameWd}{Rev.}{\@ACUrev}\kern-\fboxrule%
  \AUCBox{0.125\AUCFrameWd}{Page}{\scshape\thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage}}%
};%
\end{tikzpicture}%
  }
}
\makeatother

\Description{\vskip-2ex%
  Description line 1 \\
  Description line 2 \\
  Description line 3 \\
}
\LibNum{Doc 12345}
\Rev{---}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[2-20]

\end{document}
```

An image of the document:

[image]

A zoomed-in image of the header:

[image]

Comment: Wow, this is amazing. That second version was exactly what I need. I never would have seen that method, and probably would have spend a few more days trying to figure it out. This definitely pointed me in the right direction! Is there anywhere I could look up some info on how this was done, or what I should be looking at? Also, I tried modifying the header box size, and it seems like it pushes the "Description" label up above the boxes (see: http://i.imgur.com/9IJF0vS.png ). Is there anything else I need to change besides the fbox minipage size? (I'm using 1.5cm)

Comment: @AlexCU The problem with `1.5cm` for the height of the `minipage`s is that there was not enough space left to accommodate three lines of text in the "Description" field. I've made some modifications to the code, using now `1.5cm` for the minipages. The documentation of the packages (follow the links I provided) can be useful to understand the code.

Comment: @AlexCU I added some explanatory comments to the code in my updated answer.

Comment: This is perfect. Thanks again. I went ahead and played with it, and your comments help make a lot of sense with it. Thanks again!